# In Vert.x `SharedData`, what is the difference between `getClusterWideMap(String name)` and `getAsyncMap(String name)`?

Tags: java, cluster-computing, vert.x

The two APIs, [`getClusterWideMap(String)`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/shareddata/SharedData.html#getClusterWideMap-java.lang.String-) and [`getAsyncMap(String)`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/shareddata/SharedData.html#getAsyncMap-java.lang.String-) look identical in their requirements and the result type, and the documentation is also similar - though slightly different in a confusing way, for example the warning on cluster latency appears only for `getAsyncMap()` and not for `getClusterWideMap()`.

Answer (score 1):

From reading the source code ([For example, for the current 4.3.4 version](https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/blob/4.3.4/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/shareddata/impl/SharedDataImpl.java#L53)), it can be seen that the code to handle the "cluster manager" API is identical. The only difference between `getClusterWideMap()` and `getAsyncMap()` is that the former throws an exception if there is no "cluster manager" while the latter will return a local async map for the same configuration. Compare with `getLocalAsyncMap()` that always returns a local map, regardless of the existence of a "cluster manager".

I'm assuming the extra latency warning for `getAsyncMap()` is there to warn users about the difference in performance between "development mode" (where clustering is likely not enabled) and "production mode" (where clustering is probably enabled), while users of `getClusterWideMap()` can only test their code in a clustering environment and should therefor already be aware of the latency behvior.